# Compare 2 generic lists and return missing values from list b

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have 2 generic lists.

List 1 is populated with products from a database and List 2 is populated with products from a webservice.

I am wanting to compare lists and any values that are not in List 2 add them to List 3.

I have tried

```
List<ProductModel> productsToAdd = productsInDatabase.Except(productsFromService).ToList();
```

However all results are displayed even tho product already is in the database.

What am I doing wrong? do I need to somehow use Except but use an Id field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use overloaded version of Except method and pass equality comparer: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx)